# Basis of an outer product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Say we have 2 vector, *a* ∈ $R^a$ and b ∈ $R^b$, and we compute $ab^T$ is their outer product. We know that each column in $ab^T$ is a linear combination of the first column.

Therefore, is it correct to say that $c_1$=1st column of $ab^T$ is the unique basis of span($ab^T$)?

And, is it right to say that span($ab^T$) = span($a$)?

Comment: The first column might be $0$ (if the first entry in $b$ is $0$). You need $c$ to be the first _non-zero_ column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more correct to say that the columnspace of $ab^\top$ is $\operatorname{span}(a)$ (unless $b = 0$, in which case the columnspace is trivial). If you write $\operatorname{span}(ab^\top)$, then I would interpret this, without further context, as the set of all scalar multiples of the matrix $ab^\top$, i.e. the span of the single vector $ab^\top$ in the vector space of appropriately-sized matrices.

Comment: Thank you - so how could we define span($ab^T$)?

Comment: As I said: the set of scalar multiples of $ab^\top$. I'm confused as to what you're after here. Do you want the span of the columns of $ab^\top$? In which case, this is $\operatorname{colspace}(ab^\top)$. Do you want the span of the vector $ab^\top$ in the vector space of appropriately sized matrices? Then you want $\operatorname{span}(ab^\top)$.

Comment: My confusion comes from "the span of the vector $ab^T$ in the vector space of appropriately sized matrices" - isn't $ab^T$ a *a*x*b* matrix and not a vector? And shouldn't span($ab^T$) = to all the possible linear combinations of the columns in $ab^T$? (hence the scalar multiples of a)

Comment: To the first question, it is an $a \times b$ matrix (though I don't like using $a, b$ both as dimensions and as vectors!), which **does** make it a vector in the vector space of $a \times b$ matrices! It's not a vector in $\Bbb{R}^a$ or $\Bbb{R}^b$, but it is a vector in $\Bbb{R}^{a \times b}$. To answer your second question, no, all possible linear combinations of the columns in $ab^\top$ is $\operatorname{colspace}(ab^\top)$, not $\operatorname{span}(ab^\top)$. Matrices are not the same as sets of column vectors.

Comment: Got it, now it is clear - thanks vm!